# One-Sided Limit Evaluation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I am currently struggling with a homework problem. Actually, it is a part of the problem since it is divided into sections. My problem is the following:

Consider the following boundary value problem 
$-\epsilon u''+u'=2x $ on $(0,1)$, with conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$. Here $\epsilon >0$ is a fixed constant.

I am asked to solve the ODE and find its exact solution. By way of Undetermined Coefficients, I got $u(x) = \frac{2\epsilon+1}{e^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}-1} + (2\epsilon +1) \frac{e^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}x}}{1-e^{\frac{1}{\epsilon}}} + x^2 +2\epsilon x$.

What I am asked to prove by evaluation  is that
$\lim_{x\to a} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} u(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \lim_{x\to a} u(x)$ for any $a \in [0,1)$ and that 
$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} u(x) \neq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \lim_{x\to 1^-} u(x).$

My difficulties arise in the limit evaluation. I tried taking natural logs of everything, but I believe I made it more complicated in the process. Any and every assistance in this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance for taking the time to read the long post.